# Is there any way in bash/awk, to prints out 1st column of inputed file(1st columns are IPv4s and IPv6s), and convert that to their hostnames?

Tags: bash, awk

I’m doing simple bash script that is basically working with files and basic bash functions. However I’ve crossed something I don’t know how to deal with. I need to convert 1st column of inputed file IPv4/v6 to their hostname and prints that out. w

I know, that to print out 1st column is good to use awk | ‘{print $1}’, and to find host of IP is good nslookup, but I can’t quite put those together to echo out that IP column as HOSTNAME column.

This is how I print out 1st column. Parameter passed into function is a filename.

```
function ip_echo(){
    cat $1 | awk '{print $1}’
}
```

Comment: UUOC and unquoted variable: change `cat $1 | awk '{print $1}’` to `awk '{print $1}’ "$1"`. You can/should also get rid of the word `function` so your whole script becomes just `ip_echo() { awk '{print $1}’ "$1"; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/649551/bash-reverse-dns-lookup-of-active-ip-addresses) to get sense how to do it.

In short, your command should use `dig` and reverse lookup to translate the IP's into their hostnames.

Finally, your bash command should be look like this -

```
cat $1 | awk '{print $1}' | while read count ip; do printf "%d " $count; printf "%s " $ip; dig +noall +answer -x $ip; done
```

Comment: wrt `cat $1 | awk '{print $1}' | while read count ip` - theres a UUOC but more importantly awk is outputting 1 string while you're trying to read 2 strings and if you're using a shell read loop like that then you don't need awk at all.